# Двойная рамка вокруг ячеек таблицы <table>

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, таблицы, табличная-верстка

Я новичок. Пытаюсь создать таблицу в html

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.hstyle {
    text-align: center;
}

.calltable tr td {
    /*border-spacing: 10px;*/
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid royalblue;
}

.calltable {
    margin-top: 30px;
    /*border-spacing: 40px;*/
    border: 2px solid royalblue;    
}

#btns {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#addcall {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;   
}

#deletecall {
    border: 1px solid rgb(254, 0, 0);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(254, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;       
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Журнал вызовов</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calllog.css"></link>   
</head>
<body>  
    <h1 class="hstyle">Журнал вызовов</h1>
    <div id="btns">
        <button id="addcall">Добавить</button>
        <button id="deletecall">Удалить</button>
    </div>  
    <table class="calltable">
        <th>
            <td>
                №
            </td>
            <td>
                Дата/Время
            </td>
            <td>
                Входящий абонент
            </td>
            <td>
                Телефон входящего абонента
            </td>
            <td>
                Исходящий абонент
            </td>
            <td>
                Телефон исходящего абонента
            </td>   
            <td>
                Продолжительность
            </td>
            <td>
                Оператор абонента
            </td>
            <td>
                Стоимость вызова
            </td>   
        </th>
    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Как убрать двойную рамку вокруг ячеек и сделать одинарную?

Comment: Вот же селектор для ячеек `.calltable tr td`

Comment: @nazarpunk я обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вы накопипастили кучу ненужного для вопроса кода? Рекомендую почитать про [border-collapse](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-collapse).

```css
.calltable {
  margin-top: 30px;
  /* border: 2px solid royalblue; <-- урбрать */
  border-collapse: collapse; /* <-- добавить */
}

.calltable td {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid royalblue;
}
```

```html
<table class="calltable">
  <th>
    <td>
      №
    </td>
    <td>
      Дата/Время
    </td>
    <td>
      Входящий абонент
    </td>
    <td>
      Телефон входящего абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Исходящий абонент
    </td>
    <td>
      Телефон исходящего абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Продолжительность
    </td>
    <td>
      Оператор абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Стоимость вызова
    </td>
  </th>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
td(обращение по тегу){

border: 1px solid blue;

}
```

а если ти не в scss пишешь тогда:

```
.calltable tr td{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

бл ну лан обновил так обновил

Всм одинарную?ТИпа только с одной сторони?Ну тогда border-right

Comment: @Iox  я обновил вопрос.

Comment: Всм одинарную?ТИпа только с одной сторони?Ну тогда border-right

Comment: Только с одной сторони или как?Если только с одной сторони тогда border-bottom или border-top хз че те нужно(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border) -рекоменудю прочитать

Comment: @Iox минусовал не я (поэтому на меня не обижайтесь).